# ACTION_MOVE -> ACTION_UP is ok, but ACTION_DOWN -> ACTION_UP is not working on LG d802

Tags: android, event-handling, surfaceview

I have made an image coloring game. I am testing my program on different several devices (phones and tablets) which I can get chance to use. It works properly for most of them but there is a strage behaviour on **LG d802 phone**. an ACTION_UP event can occur after ACTION_MOVE but I cannot detect an ACTION_UP event just after ACTION_DOWN. Therefore, I can produce "move" but I cannot produce "click" behaviour. Do you know why?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent olay) {

    switch(olay.getAction())
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            ren.x = olay.getX();
            ren.y = olay.getY();
            ren.touch_state = 1;                    
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
            ren.x = olay.getX();
            ren.y = olay.getY();
            ren.touch_state = 2;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            ren.x = olay.getX();
            ren.y = olay.getY();
            ren.touch_state = 0;
        }
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It is very strange, just because it is very difficult perform ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP without calling ACTION_MOVE. Could you provide the code and log, please?

Comment: By far most of the times at most of the devices an ACTION_MOVE will be delivered. If you want to simulate clicks you ignore the ACTION_MOVE between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP.

Comment: Ok, thanks for code, so, try to add Log.i("ACTION", "action " + olay.getAction); - and see logs, is action_up really not occur on LG, if true - we will continue investigating))

Comment: I had tried it. I got the results by this method. But LG device does not belongs to me :(. So I cannot test it in usb debugging mode. But I will get it on next monday from my friend. I will share the results with you.

Comment: @jboi ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP without ACTION_MOVE can be produced by galaxy s2 and other samsungs devices which I have used. LG d802 behaves strangely.

Comment: Ok, great. I'm asking it, beacuse it is really strange behaviour, and most likely that this action handling is incorrects, than this action isn't occur at all. So, when you will have more info - let us know, it is really interesting and important case, if it is true!

Comment: I think that it is my fault because the other painting softwares are running correctly on this LG. But the interesting point is that my game is running very good on the other devices. There must be a difference between this device and the others.

Comment: Yap, so we are waiting for your results ;)